# How to choose a different property instead of `key` in nvd3

Tags: nvd3.js

All nvd3 examples (which I've found) look like this:

```
return [
{
  values: sin,      //values - represents the array of {x,y} data points
  key: 'Sine Wave', //key  - the name of the series.
  color: '#ff7f0e'  //color - optional: choose your own line color.
}, ...]
```

I want to use a function which would use different keys based on the size of the chart / drawing area.

So if I have a large drawing area I have space for the whole name `Sine Wave` and in small areas I'd just display `sin`.

Yes, I could go through the series and update the `key` property, but it would be easier to put all the necessary data into the object and choose on render time, which key should be used.

Comment: Are you concerned about space in the legend, the tooltip, or both?

Comment: mainly the legend. Some users choose over a dozen items to show and than the whole chart is just a legend on small screens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `chart.legend.key()`

```
 chart.legend.key(function(d){
     // Return the key you want for series d here based on screen realestate
     // FYI: The default would return d.key
 });
```

So it could look something like this:

```
    function setLegendKeys(d){
      var width = document.body.clientWidth;
      var abbreviations = {
        'Sine Wave': 'sin',
        'Cosine Wave': 'cos'
      };
      if (width < 500){
        return abbreviations[d.key];
      }
      return d.key;
    }

    chart.legend.key(setLegendKeys)
```

See this Plunk for a live example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/lisKuZ5ivj25QhyjlQUW?p=preview